# Does a word meaning "Created Recklessly for Temporary Use" exist?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, adjectives

Imagine you are surviving in the wilderness traveling in a wandering manner. You've found this landscape that is wonderfully abundant in food and basking in a very favorable climate. Therefore, you decide that this is your new residence.

Night is approaching, so you haphazardly piece together a makeshift shelter to make for a more enjoyable living experience while you get your act together.

This shelter is only temporary. After you've become familiar with the land and have gathered finer resources, you will begin creating a proper home complete with securities, amenities, and furnishings.

The word I am looking for is an adjective meaning something similar to "created recklessly for temporary use."

> The shelter you were building on your first night was a(n) ________
>   abode.

The words and phrases "ad-hoc", "off the cuff", "on the run" came to my mind, but none of those are understood to mean what I am trying to communicate (in fact, two of them are not even close). If you think of a word with a meaning that you believe to be similar to what I am searching for, I'd love to hear from you!

Thank you.

Comment: _Recklessly_ is the wrong word here: if an action is reckless, it is risky and foolish. Building a makeshift shelter is neither risky nor foolish.

Comment: VTC as "Unclear what you're asking". I have no idea if you really want the word to connotate "recklessly" or not. As @TonyK says, "recklessly" is probably the wrong word here, as none of the rest of your detailed question has anything remotely connected to "reckless". I posted a comment earlier asking for clarification, but it's been summarily deleted by a mod without a response from you.

Comment: If you take out the word "abode" you get the whole meaning with *lean-to*, which could be upgraded to *shanty* before working on something more substantial.

Comment: The question is protected, so I don't have enough reputation to post an answer, but I'd definitely upvote an answer proposing "provisional", for which the first definition Google provides is "arranged or existing for the present, possibly to be changed later."

Comment: A modern option, if you can use American vernacular:  The shelter you were building on your first night was a **hack**.  But I agree with Lawrence below:  **makeshift** is the most appropriate choice here.

Comment: I'm a programmer, recklessly creating things for temporary use is essentially my job description.

Comment: For me, the phrase ["quick and dirty"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=quick+and+dirty&*) comes to mind. From a programming perspective, a "quick and dirty" solution is often used to temporarily solve a problem while you work to implement a more permanent solution. Not sure if it'd count here, though, since you're asking for a single word.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor's "provisional" is pretty great. Also "stand-in". Many of the ones below highlight the shoddiness but not the temporariness...

Comment: I've proposed the suggestion made by @JoshuaTaylor in comments, after considering *interim*.

Comment: @ebyrob A 'lean-to' requires an existing building or wall to be built up against, doesn't it?

Comment: @Spagirl In the wilderness, the "existing wall" could be a large rock or even a tree or two. In the absence of any of those, you might prop up the lean-to with a stick.

Comment: Would Stopgap fit?

Answer (score 139):

Your own term, *makeshift*, works here. The dictionary entry provides several examples. I've selected one that relates to the context you provided.

> **Makeshift** *adjective*
>   Acting as an interim and temporary measure.
>   ‘About 109,000 people are living in makeshift shelters made from blue and white plastic sheeting.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/makeshift)

Comment: I can recall several occasions where astronauts created make-shift and jury-rigged solutions to serious problems. None of those solutions were done recklessly or without regard to any hazards. Out of necessity they were quite the opposite, but were make-shift and jury-rigged nevertheless.

Comment: @CanisLupus Agreed that *makeshift* dwellings might have been constructed in a non-reckless manner. However, since the OP is after an adjective to describe the dwelling rather than the construction activity, perhaps some latitude can be allowed.

Comment: @CanisLupus As pointed out repeatedly in the comments, the question contradicts itself, since the desire to put up any kind of shelter whatsoever means that you _do_ have regard for the hazards of being exposed. If "reckless" was supposed to indicate hasty construction without regard for quality, then _makeshift_ would not be my choice, but there is no answer if you take the question literally.

Answer (score 96):

**jury-rigged** (from jury-rig)

> to erect, construct, or arrange in a makeshift fashion

also

> to build or put together (a simple device or structure) using the materials that you have available

-[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jury%E2%80%93rig)

The term is originally from a nautical context to describe a temporary fix, but has come into wider use for any type of make-shift contrivance or repair.

Comment: For ever-so-slightly different connotations, consider [jerry-rigged](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132868/jury-rigged-or-jerry-rigged).

Comment: I've also seen just "rigged" or "rig job" used.

Comment: my feeling is that jury-rigged/jerry-rigged strongly implies recklessness (as opposed to makeshift.)  great answer!

Answer (score 87):

**Slapdash**:

> (*adv.*) in a hasty, haphazard manner: He assembled the motor slapdash.
>
> (*adj.*) hasty and careless; offhand: a slapdash answer. ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slapdash))

This definition tacitly implies that the creation is not likely remain intact or of much use for long.

Slapdash combines *slap* and *dash*:

*slap* is to put or place promptly and sometimes haphazardly ([Dictionary.com #7](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slap?s=t)).

*dash* is to do something quickly or roughly ([Dictionary.com #4 and #10](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dash?s=t)).

Comment: I think this is the best answer provided so far. It indicates not only that the work is makeshift or temporary, but also that it's done hastily and without regard for accepted standards of quality, probably in response to an emergency.

Comment: I think *slapdash* emphasizes carelessness, whereas *jury-/jerry-rigged* and *makeshift* emphasize minimal resources.

Comment: Sorry, Canis, I don't think this is right. It doesn't imply temporary at all - it just indicates the quality of the work and perhaps the attitude of the perpetrator. I've seen slapdash work hanging around causing pain for decades. In the questioner's scenario, my shelter would be makeshift and jury-rigged, but definitely not slapdash.

Comment: @SusanW I've seen makeshift and jury-rigged repairs that ended up hanging around for decades too. Just sayin'...

Comment: @barbecue yeah, too true, same here! :-)  Hmm, there definitely a thing that _slapdash_ is derogatory in terms of workmanship; excessively careless, regardless of circumstances. Is this an irregular verb? I improvise, you jury-rig, and he's slapdash...

Answer (score 43):

In UK English we have the word [Bodge](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bodge)

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT] British  informal  Make or repair (something) badly or
>   clumsily. ‘the door was bodged together from old planks’

This generally implies a task which is done hastily or inelegantly but is at least barely adequate. This doesn't necessarily imply that the person doing the task is incompetent but that they didn't have  the time, resources or inclination to do anything better.

The word comes from the traditional craft of the Bodging, making tools and furniture from unseasoned wood, especially items turned on a [pole lathe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_lathe). The sense here is that the items were made cheaply and quickly rather than badly as such.

Note that this is distinct from *botched* which does imply that a task was carried out incompetently.

Alternatively the word [hasty](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hasty) can be use as an adjective to describe something produced as quickly as possible. Saying you built a *hasty shelter* would certainly fit what you have in mind.

Answer (score 40):

A frequently used word in this context is ***improvised***.

> The shelter you were building on your first night was a(n)
>   ***improvised*** abode.

ODO:

> **[improvised](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/improvised)**
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** Done or made using whatever is available; makeshift.
>
> ‘we slept on improvised beds’
>
> ‘Someone is apparently being evacuated from an improvised shelter.’

Also, ***crude*** may work.

ODO:

> **[crude](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/crude)**
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **2** Constructed in a rudimentary or makeshift way.
>
> ‘The training facility was large, but seemed fairly crude, and in
>   disrepair

Answer (score 28):

In the tech world at least, we'd probably use the term **hack**.

From the hacker culture mainstay, the [Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hack.html):

> 1. n. Originally, a quick job that produces what is needed, but not well.

To a professional engineer, a solution that isn't done "well" adds to [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt), and so has an implied temporary nature.

So to complete your example, we might say:

> The shelter you were building on your first night was a hack.

Note that some may consider a "hack" to require an aspect of cleverness, so it may not be a perfect fit.

Comment: I think that you hit on the problem with "hack" quite well: To me, it has two related but distinct meanings, namely "creatively exploring un-anticipated behaviors of complex systems" (e.g. the GPL is a hack of the copyright system) and the one you quoted. You should always either qualify it further ("beautiful hack", "quick hack") or it should be absolutely clear from context which one you mean. Your example sentence does that very well. Only the former definition requires cleverness, ingenuity, and creativity. For the latter definition, cleverness is actually seen as a negative, since we …

Comment: … aspire for code to be clear, unambiguous, easy to understand, easy to follow, simple, and concise – cleverness is usually *not* what you want.

Comment: Of course, in many, many projects, “temporary hacks” have a tendency to end up permanent... but then I would guess that’s often the case for all kinds of “temporary” solutions.

Comment: Isn't that a kludge, not a hack?

Comment: Hack is also used to refer to a writer who quickly produces low-quality output, and hack work can mean such output as well.

Comment: hacks typically are clever, but that doesn't make some mutually exclusive in the desired case; just because the solution is temporary/thrown-together doesn't mean it isn't clever. indeed, many temporary solutions only exist because they are clever.

Answer (score 20):

You might consider the informal word **kludge**, implying something that's functional, but poorly planned and haphazardly assembled.

Oxford Living Dictionaries [defines](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/kludge) it as:

> **kludge**
>   *(also cludge, kluge)*
>   *NOUN*
>   *informal*
>
> An ill-assorted collection of parts assembled to fulfill a particular purpose.
>
> *‘Such a database would be a kludge of existing databases; databases that are incompatible, full of erroneous data, and unreliable.’*
>
> *‘The vertebrate eye does very well indeed, but it is a kludge.’*
>
> *‘On the corner of Eversholt Street and Euston is a St Pancras New Church, a neo-classical kludge which at the time of its construction in 1822 was the most expensive church building since St Paul's.’*
>
> *‘It wouldn't have been perfect, but it almost certainly would have been better than the kludge we're ending up with.’*

According to the same dictionary, it can also be used as a verb:

> *‘I initially coded the blog's template by kludging together a lot of stuff without really knowing what I was doing.’*
>
> *‘So there is nothing that the Google desktop offers I can't already kludge.’*
>
> *‘The details aren't specific, and feel a little kludged.’*
>
> *‘The original network - I'm sure our technologists wouldn't like this - but it was kludged together through landlines’*
>
> *‘Thus you either change the new code, or try and kludge the old code, or hack around the old code with a whole new bit.’*
>
> *‘It's well worth taking the time to add extra comments and clean up any kludged code.’*
>
> *‘One can add a middle initial, but this is just kludging it.’*

Although *kludge* has its origins in computer slang, according to its [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge), *This term is used in diverse fields such as computer science, aerospace engineering, Internet slang, evolutionary neuroscience, and government.*

Comment: This is definitely from computer slang, but really embodies the intent I think.  "hack" definitely doesn't as it includes the idea of cleverness.  Altough, kludges though ugly, and even "stupid", can often be highly effective.  (which might run counter to the intent)

Answer (score 17):

There's also ***[ramshackle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ramshackle)***:

> 1:  appearing ready to collapse :  rickety
>       2:  carelessly or loosely constructed *a ramshackle plot*
>   *<sub>from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ramshackle)</sub>*

This has the added benefit, to my mind, of containing the syllable "shack" right there in the middle, thus linking it to your idea of a small, temporary building.  (Although this is, etymologically speaking, entirely coincidental; *ramshackle* apparently derives from the word *ransack*.)

Comment: I always hear *ramshackle* to describe once-sturdy structures in a state of disrepair.

Answer (score 13):

> **[impromptu](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/impromptu)** adjective ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/impromptu))
>
> 1.made or done without previous preparation:
>   *an impromptu address to the unexpected crowds.*
>
> **2.suddenly or hastily prepared, made, etc.:
>   *an impromptu dinner.***
>
> 3.improvised; having the character of an improvisation.

" The shelter you were building on your first night was an ***impromptu*** abode.

Comment: Impromptu doesn't seem to convey the meaning of recklessness ask for in the question.

Comment: *reckless* means *without caution; careless* that's synonymous enough with *hastily prepared*.

Comment: Impromptu means without forethought or prior planning, but does not mean poor quality or unreliable. It's perfectly possible for an impromptu action to be of high quality.

Answer (score 12):

Just to provide another option, you could use **throwaway**

> (adj) Denoting or relating to products that are intended to be discarded after being used once or a few times.
>
> (n) A thing intended to be discarded after brief use.
>
> [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/throwaway)

In your example:

> The shelter you were building on your first night was a **throwaway** abode.

It doesn't explicitly cover something poorly constructed, but that is often implied within the context.

Answer (score 9):

The phrase you're looking for is **ad hoc**:

> **ad hoc** created or done for a particular purpose as necessary
>
> **[ad hoc](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad%20hoc)** for the particular end or case at hand without consideration of wider application

Another word that accurately telegraphs such an intent is **expedient**:

> [**expedient**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/expedient) convenient and practical although possibly improper or immoral
>
> [**expedient**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expedient) Something contrived or used to meet an urgent need
>
> [**expedient**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expedient) Suitable or efficient for accomplishing a purpose

Comment: "Ad hoc" is listed as a not-quite-right answer in the original post.

Answer (score 7):

Another term is [*lash-up (N)* (dictionary.com)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lash-up):

1. a hastily made or arranged device, organization, etc.
2. any improvised arrangement.

In your example sentence: *The shelter you were building on your first night was a lash-up -- but at least it kept the rain off*

Comment: The British definition is even better: "temporary connection of equipment for experimental or emergency use"

Comment: @HonoredMule I get the impression it's a predominantly British phrase. But that's just an impression.

Answer (score 7):

You might consider the word [***cobbled***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cobble)

*"Roughly produced or assembled from available parts or elements"*

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind being vulgar, [**half-assed**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/half-assed) or [**half-arsed**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/half-arsed) could be used in the example sentence. It means haphazard, done without care or proper effort, and is a possible synonym for other answers already provided.

It's not a great choice, because it usually means that the work was low quality due to lack of interest or effort rather than urgency.

"The camp counselor said I had to make a shelter, so I built a half-assed lean-to from a broom and a shower curtain."

Comment: These terms only describe the quality of effort, without clarifying permanency of the result.  Crude language is rarely going to offer sufficient nuance when it is by definition sloppy and imprecise.

Comment: Yep, and that's why I said that in the answer itself. However I disagree that the vulgarity itself being sloppy and imprecise somehow makes it unsuitable for conveying sloppiness and imprecision.

Comment: It can certainly can, but such uses convey information about the vulgarity's source, not its subject/object.  A "f*cking canoe" only offers clarification of "canoe" if I literally mean "canoe designed or designated for copulating."

Comment: What you describe is essentially the reason I used "rarely" rather than "never."

Comment: However "that f-ing canoe" can mean "the canoe which is the current target of my ire."

Answer (score 4):

This might work:

**Janky** (also jank) - *adjective*
Of extremely poor or unreliable quality.

- 'the software is pretty janky’
- 'there's hardly anywhere to eat other than a janky food court’
- 'the car is embarrassing to drive because it's so jank’

Answer (score 3):

Helter-skelter (MW)

in undue haste, confusion, or disorder

in a haphazard manner

Answer (score 2):

Like many of the other suggestions here in the phrase "**field expedient**" does not necessarily imply recklessness, lack of care or insufficiency, but does cover cases where one is forced to make do with whatever tools and materials are at hand.

And it fails to be a single word, but it is used as an adjective and can lend a connotation of 'the best that could be managed' to a description that might otherwise carry a whiff of 'unprofessional'.

Comment: The adjective would be *expidious*, if you can use the word without thinking of powdermilk biscuits.

Answer (score 1):

> This shelter is only temporary. After you've become familiar with the land and have gathered finer resources, you will begin creating a proper home complete with securities, amenities, and furnishings.

In this exact sense, wherein someone creates a structure in order to facilitate later building a more advanced / permanent structure, we may call it a '**bootstrap**' shelter. (**Bootstrap**, here, being an adjective derived from an idiom about "pulling yourself up by your own bootstraps" which has its own rich history)

*adjective
3.
relying entirely on one's efforts and resources:
The business was a bootstrap operation for the first ten years.*

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bootstrap

Many examples of native english speakers using the term 'bootstrap' with this exact connotation can be found in the community for the game 'factorio':

https://www.google.com/search?q=factorio+bootstrap+factory

Answer (score 1):

### Provisional

(also proposed by **Joshua Taylor** as a comment)

From the [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/provisional):

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1)  Arranged or existing for the present, possibly to be changed later.
>
> ...

ODO examples include:

> ‘It was a kind of empire built on very **provisional** and tentative things that might happen.’
>
> ‘In the meantime, the **provisional** festival programme has thrown up some intriguing possibilities for a couple of good nights on the town.’

Your example would read:

> The shelter you were building on your first night was a **provisional** abode.

Answer (score 1):

Growing up and maybe it's where I'm from (East Coast, VA), the expression I've always used, and most commonly hear anyone say is:

***"Quick and dirty"***

For example, I'm a former Firefighter and when I was in Recruit School one of the instructors would always say it if we were in the field on a practical day and someone was being too timid or overly 'perfect' about a walking extinguisher drill, he'd yell that out. That was when basically two rows of controlled fire lit left and right of you and you walk down the middle extinguishing side to side to get through in order to reach an unconcious patient at the other end. If a person stood there hitting each row slow and really laying into the ABC until he didn't even see an ember, it was always,

**"SON, THIS IS A BACKYARD WITH AN UNRESPONSIVE PATIENT TEN FEET AHEAD, JUST GIVE IT THE QUICK AND DIRTY VERSION SO THAT YOU KNOCK IT DOWN ENOUGH UNDER CONTROL AND MAKE PATIENT CONTACT!"**

And to clarify, most often 'version' kinda tags it's way along. As above, 'quick and dirty version'. In my head it just implies every second counts, and get done just enough with whatever is hindering you from achieving the primary goal, whether it's getting to a patient, or in proposed scenario of yours, throwin' together a quick and dirty version of the shelter. Ah and I forgot also, almost always you'll hear just following that "it doesn't have to be perfect." Well, either preceeding or following, you'll hear it both ways.

That extra phrase kinda drives the point home that the most important thing is that you get it made or a job done, even if it's the worst possible version of it, as the worst shelter is better than no shelter at nightfall when the temperature drops or there is a need for concealment.

Sorry for the long-winded explanation, just wanted to make it as clear as I could why it seems appropriate, and give a really black-and-white experience of mine for context regarding it's nuance. Hope this fits in with what you were going for. It's literally what I would personally say without thinking if we were in a situation like that together.

Cheers!