# What are terms for a person who makes things work (and improves upon) by fixing, modifying, or creating only from spare parts because they are poor?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What are some names, labels, terms, slang, and/or figures of speech; for a person who (can quickly and 100% dependably) makes things (devices, systems, machines, processes, etc.) work (not only successfully performs original functionality but always improves upon in many ways, such as: extended functions, added functions, reduction in necessary time and/or energy required for operation, increased user-friendliness/comfort/ease-of-use, aesthetics, etc.) by the act(s) of fixing, modifying, and/or creating from scratch; only from scraps, spares, parts, and/or pulls that are readily available, because:

(any, all, or combination of)

1. no time nor money is available to procure a replacement
2. no time nor money is available to procure original replacement parts
3. no time nor money is available to procure non-original but well-suited new parts

..?

Phrases such as "problem solver" or "critical thinker" are not necessarily what I am searching for, as these examples are a bit too "general" or "generic" in that they are used so commonly that the talent/skill/expertise I am seeking to define as something unordinary and priceless is watered-down into banality.

*MacGyver* aired for seven years on broadcast television simply showcasing the character's unique abilities that solved multiple critical issues all at the same time. What would MacGyver's resume look like? I don't think anyone would understand his abilities if it simply stated phrases like: "works well under pressure", "quick and efficient", "thinks outside of the box"...

So the answers I am seeking, would be closely related to the interdisciplinary skills on the MacGyver character's resume, but in the context of my original question.

**Thank you** in advance to anyone that devotes any thought to this question.

[image: importance suggested]

Comment: “MacGyver” *is* a verb, meaning “to make something work with the available tools and materials”. So MacGyver’s resume could say that he is good at MacGyvering.

Comment: related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381192/does-a-word-meaning-created-recklessly-for-temporary-use-exist

Comment: One who improvises

Comment: Is them being poor really a relevant criteria? Maybe they enjoy fixing things without spending money regardless of their financial status. Is it that they have to do it because they don't have money? Even if that is the case, it is a tad too specific and not relevant in my opinion. Consider removing "because they are poor" and  money related criteria.

Comment: The corresponding agent noun jury-rigger doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: Tinkerer,  an unskilled person who tries to fix or mend. synonyms: fiddler. type of: unskilled person. a person who lacks technical training.

Answer (score 2):

*Improviser* fits your criteria, except that it doesn’t incorporate poverty.

William R. Compton, in his book about the Apollo Program, said of Apollo 13, "Only a heroic effort of real-time improvisation by mission operations teams saved the crew."

After an explosion, the Apollo 13 crew needed to find a way to remove carbon dioxide from their cabin. One astronaut not on the mission worked in a mock-up of the cabin to use what was available to solve parts of the problem, including using items such as the cover of a manual. Other ground crew contributed.  Great story, great movie (there’s more than one).

Details [here.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13)

Answer (score 1):

The term **DIYer** (from DIY, short for "do it yourself") might work.

[Cambridge defines it as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/diyer)

> someone who decorates or repairs their home, or makes things for their home, rather than paying someone else to do it for them

[Collins defines it as:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/diyer)

> a person who builds or repairs things for himself or herself, usually in the home

Answer (score 1):

**bricoleur** has the meaning:

One who makes from whatever is available.

The word could be used figuratively of someone with mechanical or engineering aptitude who improvises using parts on hand, whatever they find on the shelves in their workshop.

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bricoleur#:~:text=bricoleur%20(plural%20bricoleurs),using%20whatever%20materials%20are%20available](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bricoleur#:%7E:text=bricoleur%20(plural%20bricoleurs),using%20whatever%20materials%20are%20available).

But it doesn't connote  *elegance of design*, *simplicity of design*, *improvement or extension of functionality* that you seem to be looking for as well. For that **tinkerer** might work, as a kind of understatement, since people who **tinker with** things often improve them, substituting random parts on hand that might actually perform better than the original design or work more reliably.

You may need to enlist the services of an adjective. You could call someone an **inventive tinkerer** to imply that they don't just kludge things together but that they find clever novel ways to improve devices
that already exist, or to combine features of existing devices in order to devise something to meet a new need.

My neighbor is such a guy. He is a talented machinist with extensive training in electronics as well, and he has worked for years in the fabrication department of a multi-national corporation, making all kinds of gizmos the company needed when a ready-made device didn't exist.

Comment: "Bricoleur" would be a good answer for a *French Language and Usage* forum. In French, this word refers to a kind of jack-of-all-trades and handyman. But, I am not sure that this term is common in US or UK.

Comment: @Graffito **bricoleur** is used by English speakers. **bricoleur** and **bricolage** are defined by Websters, Collins, Cambridge, Oxford dictionaries, among others. But relatively few English speakers are familiar with it, true.