# simple present tense

Tags: differences, word-usage

Noob question: I've been following a youtube channel called "Jerry rig everything" for a while now. I'm little confused as to why it's not "Jerry *rigs* everything" since jerry is his name and I think we always use *s/es* with a verb whenever we refer to a third person in a simple present tense. Can someone please explain me on this?

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132868/jury-rigged-or-jerry-rigged . It must be a pun on the presenter's name and the phrase 'to jerry-rig'. I've never seen this expression before but guessed it was a variant of 'jury-rig', which means to make a temporary repair, such as replacing the broken mast of a ship at sea with whatever wood is available.

Comment: Sounds like Jerry does not show how he fixes things, but how _you can fix things_ as he does. His name is a secondary joke. His point is to demonstrate how to fix things in do-it-yourself projects, not merely to show that Jerry did it. The title means 'Use my examples to improvise fixes to everything,' or 'Slap it all together as I do.'