# Did or didn't the "jury-" prefix (jury-rigged, jury-mast) derive from "injury?"

Tags: etymology

OED has an interesting definition of ***jury-mast***

> a. Naut. A temporary mast put up in place of one that has been broken or carried away.

The etymology provided is brief and leaves an open question:

> *Origin unknown.* Apparently either a corruption of some earlier name, or a jocular appellation invented by sailors. **For the suggestion that it may have been short for injury-mast, no supporting evidence has been found.**

The earliest cited use in OED of *jury-mast* is from 1616.

This use of *jury-* as a prefix indicating that something is made as a makeshift replacement for something broken extends to the more commonly used modern term ***jury-rigged.***  An early use of this variant is from 1788:

> 1788   T. Newte Tour Eng. & Scotl. 116   The ships to be jury rigged: that is, to have smaller masts, yards, and rigging, than would be required for actual service.

The topic of jury-rigging has been discussed here: ["jury-rigged", or "jerry-rigged,"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132868/jury-rigged-or-jerry-rigged) but the posts make no mention of the "injury" connection.

Given that OED hasn't found a definitive answer, can anyone find evidence for or against the suggestion that the prefix "jury-" is related to "injury?"

Comment: I imagine the jury is still out on this one. More than one source says the origin may come ultimately from Old French ajurie, ‘aid’.

Comment: What Clare said, and see [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=j&p=10&allowed_in_frame=0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Some background on the 'jury' in 'jury-rigged' and 'jury mast'***

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) offers the same information about *jury* in the sense of (for example) *jury-rigged* that Peter Shor notes in a comment above:

> <sup>**2**</sup>**jury** adj {M[iddle] E[nglish] *jory* in *jory saile* improvised sail} (15c) improvised for temporary use, esp. in an emergency : MAKESHIFT {a *jury* mast} {a *jury* rig}

*Injury*, on the other hand has this derivation, according to the *Eleventh Collegiate*:

> {M[iddle] E[nglish] *enjuren*, fr. A[nglo-]F[rench] *enjurer*, fr. L[ate] L[atin] *injuriare*, fr. L[atin] *injuria* injury} (15c)

For its part, *The Compact Edition of the Oxford English Dictionary* (1971) has no entry for *jory*.

The only instance of *jory saile* from a fifteenth-century source that a Google Books search discloses appears in an entry for *jury-sail* in [*Middle English Sea Terms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yl0TAAAAIAAJ&q=%22jory+saile%22&dq=%22jory+saile%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJt7nQpKfUAhVRyGMKHWJUDKYQ6AEILzAC), issue 20 (1958) [combined snippets]:

> **jury-sail**
>
> **1468–70.** *Yarmouth Court Rolls* ... j velo magno et ij bonettes j meson seil j **jory saile** ... j virga pro le water seill.
>
> [**1592.** . . . **jury-mast.** See Weekley s.v.]
>
> [**1616.** Smith, *Descr. New Eng.* 50. (NED.) We had reaccommodated her a **Iury mast**, and the rest, to returne for Plimouth.]

"Weekley" is Ernest Weekly, *An Etymological Dictionary of Modern English* (1921), which offers this interesting entry for *jury-mast*:

> **jury-mast.** An obscure naut[ical] witticism. Cf. synon. F. *mât de fortune*.
>
> > I was left all alone, and let me drive in the sea five days before I could make my jury-mast {Capt Thompson, 1592}

That the "jury-mast" in Captain Thompson's account was a makeshift is evident from the slightly longer excerpt from the original that [*The Mariner's Mirror*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cqLfAAAAMAAJ&q=%22before+I+could+make+my+jury-mast%22&dq=%22before+I+could+make+my+jury-mast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv2rfCrafUAhUEjlQKHYGRAC8Q6AEIKDAA), volume 54 (1968) provides:

> Falling off from the carrack [sailing ship], when she was yielded, my mast went by the board. Then I was left all alone, and let me drive in the sea five days before I could make my **jury-mast**.

Likewise, the Captain John Smith instance refers to a makeshift mast, as evidenced by this longer extract from his [*Description of New England*](https://books.google.com/books?id=28pJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA221&dq=%22reaccommodated+her+a+Iury+mast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKg4LZsKfUAhVP1GMKHap4C5AQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22reaccommodated%20her%20a%20Iury%20mast%22&f=false) (1616):

> In the end I was furnished with a Ship of 200. and another of 50 [tons]. But ere I had sayled 120 leagues, shee broke all her masts; pumping each watch 5 or 6000 strokes: onely her spret saile remayned to spoon before the wind, till we had reaccommodated her a **Iury mast**, and the rest, to returne for *Plimouth*.

Joseph Shipley, [*Dictionary of Word Origins*](https://books.google.com/books?id=U9rh5emSEccC&q=%22jury+this+body+of+sworn+men%22&dq=%22jury+this+body+of+sworn+men%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFtcivvafUAhVPw2MKHcyeCDkQ6AEIKDAA) (1945) [combined snippets] offers this discussion of *jury* in its two fundamentally different senses:

> **jury.** This body of sworn men gets its name, from OFr. *jurée*, sworn, from L. *jurare*, j*urat—*, to swear, from *jus*, *jur—*, law. ... But the word *jury*, in such combinations as *jury-mast* and *jury-leg*, temporary (a wooden leg), is for the day?, from OFr. *jornal*, *jurnal*, *journal*, daily, from LL *diurnal—* from L. *diurnus*, from *dies*, day. Thus a *journey* was originally a day's march; a *journeyman*, a worker by the day; a *journal*, a daily record. *Journal* was first an adjective; ca. 1500 the noun (account, record, register, etc.) was dropped; by the end of the 16th c[entury] its doublet *diurnal* (coming into use ca. 1550, meaning the list of religious services for the day) had replaced *journal* as the more formal adjective for daily. *Johnny* cake is a folk change from *journey* cake.

Shipley's analysis is intriguing—and in fact it echoes a word-origin theory that goes back to Francis Grose, [*A Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4HoSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PT153&dq=%22jury-mast%22+Grose&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihgdG10KfUAhVMz2MKHTmFC_IQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=%22jury-mast%22%20Grose&f=false) (1788)—but it doesn't seem to have generated a lot of support from subsequent etymologists and commentators. Robert Hendrickson, The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins, fourth edition (2008) has this very brief entry for jury rig:

> **jury rig.** A temporary repair made on a boat to replace a broken part, most often by using something crafted on board. Ultimately from the Latin *adiutare*, to help. "We jury-rigged some fishing gear."

[*The Wordsworth Dictionary of Phrase and Fable*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IgjAJazrBWwC&pg=PA621&dq=%22jury-leg%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS67f4vKfUAhUJzWMKHTCfAGcQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=%22jury-leg%22&f=false) (2001), based on a similarly titled book by Ebenezer Brewer, who died in 1897, mentions *jury-leg* as a humorous extension of the use of *jury* in the sense of makeshift:

> **Jury Mast.** A temporary mast, a spar used for the nonce when the mast has been carried away. Th origin of the term is unknown; it has been in use for certainly over three hundred years, and was probably a bit of sailor's wit.
>
> "Jury" has been humorously tacked on to other nouns, giving to the word a makeshift or temporary significance, *e.g. Jury-leg*, a wooden leg:—
>
> > I took the leg off with my saw ... seared the stump ... and made a jury leg that he shambles about with as well as ever he did.—[Walter] Scott: *The Pirate*, ch. xxxiv.

But in Brewer himself, [*Dictionary of Phrase and Fable*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6-DQAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA694&dq=%22jury-leg%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUq8zxwKfUAhUJ_WMKHSqKDog4ChDoAQgjMAA#v=onepage&q=%22jury-leg%22&f=false) (1900) says nothing about the humorous sailors, instead confidently subscribing to the "mast for a day" theory of *jury-mast*:

> **Jury Mast.** A corruption of *joury* mast—i.e., a mast for the day, a temporary mast, being a spar used for the nonce when the mast has been carried away. (French, *jour*, a day.)

Unfortunately (but not altogether surprisingly), neither Brewer nor anyone else who argues for *joury mast* as the source of *jury mast* (which authors have done as recently as [1980](https://books.google.com/books?id=K9BGCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&dq=%22joury-mast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU4dzw7KfUAhVO4mMKHZ5XBQYQ6AEISDAG#v=onepage&q=%22joury-mast%22&f=false)) has pointed to any instance of "joury mast" or "joury-mast" in a seventeenth-century or earlier English text.

Most instances of *jury-leg* that a Google Books search finds—which are not terribly numerous but go back at least to Grose's *Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue* (1788) and in nondictionary usage to John Davis, [*Jack Ariel, Or, Life on Board an Indiaman*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FAktAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA70&dq=%22jury-leg%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix-5z8wKfUAhVC5WMKHSILDQ04UBDoAQhRMAg#v=onepage&q=%22jury-leg%22&f=false) (1847) and Jam Hannay, [*Singleton Fontenoy, R. N.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=eu5LAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA41&dq=%22jury-leg%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiirqT0wKfUAhVQ22MKHdfIATk4HhDoAQgjMAA#v=onepage&q=%22jury-leg%22&f=false) (1851)—occur in a nautical context, which tends to support Wordsworth's impression of that particular term as a jocular maritime extension from *jury mast*.

---

***Where did the 'injury' theory of 'jury-' come from?***

One propagator of the injury theory appears to be James Stormonth, who is cited in Charles Mackay, [*The Gaelic Etymology of the Languages of Western Europe: And More Especially of the English and Lowland Scotch*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Hq8VAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA243&dq=%22jury-leg%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiirqT0wKfUAhVQ22MKHdfIATk4HhDoAQg6MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22jury-leg%22&f=false) (1877):

> JURY MAST.—A mast hastily constructed by sailors in a storm, to replace a mast that has gone by the board.
>
> > A supposed corruption of *injury mast*.—STORMONTH.
> >
> > Probably from French *jour*, a day; *i. e.* a mast for the day.—WORCESTER.
>
> Gaelic.—*Diugh* (*diù* pronounced *jiù*), to-day; *re*, during; *i. e.* a mast for the day, a temporary mast.Sailors also call a wooden leg a "jury" leg, because it does temporary duty.

"Stormonth" is James Stormonth, [*Etymological and Pronouncing Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=W71DAQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22stormonth%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim_qCeyqfUAhVL92MKHdI1AMI4FBDoAQg7MAU#v=onepage&q=jury-mast&f=false) (1876), which has this subentry within its entry for *jurist*:

> **jury-mast,** *n.* (a supposed corruption of *injury-mast*), in a ship, a temporary mast placed instead of another one lost or carried away, as in a storm.

Stormonth may have drawn his suggested etymology from [*The Cabinet Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DnACAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA397&dq=%22injury+mast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUirbgyafUAhUBRWMKHUcoBxY4KBDoAQhOMAk#v=onepage&q=%22injury%20mast%22&f=false) (1871), which is notable for voicing less equivocal support for the derivation in question:

> **Jury-mast,** *n.* {Probably for *injury-mast*, one carried away by the *injury* of weather.] A temporary mast erected in a ship, to supply the place of one carried away in a tempest or an engagement, &c.

---

***Hostility to the 'injury' theory***

William Whitney, [*The Century Dictionary: An Encyclopedic Lexicon of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7G9CAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA3257&dq=%22injury+mast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8grWzyafUAhVBzWMKHV7bDnk4HhDoAQhLMAk#v=onepage&q=%22injury%20mast%22&f=false) (1889), however, is far from persuaded by the *injury-mast* attribution:

> **jury-mast** *n.* {The element *jury-*, found first in *jury-mast* and later in similar naut. compounds, *jury-rudder*, *jury-rig*, *jury-rigged*, and the slang term *jury-leg*, is usually supposed to be an abbreviation of *injury*; but this presupposes a form *injury-mast*, a highly improbable name for a new mast substituted for one which has been lost. The accent also makes an abbr. to *jury-* improbable. More improbable still are the etymologies which refer the word to Dan[ish] *kiőre*, a driving, ... or to *journey* (a *journiere* mast, i. e. a mast for the day or occasion") (Grose). It suits the conditions best to take the word as simply *jury* + *mast*, it being prob. orig. a piece of nautical humor, designating a more or less awkward mast hastily devised by the captain and carpenter consulting as a 'jury'.} Nut. a temporary mast erected on a ship, to supply the place of one that has been broken or carried away, as in a tempest or an engagement.

Walter Skeat, [*An Etymological Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vDZAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA312&dq=%22injury+mast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis-IX70afUAhXov1QKHX5OBjQ4ZBDoAQhQMAg#v=onepage&q=%22injury%20mast%22&f=false), third edition (1898 [first edition was in 1881]) shares Whitney's view that *injury-mast* is an unlikely source of *jury-mast*, although he comes out in favor of the Danish theory over the humorous "*jury* + *mast*" theory that Whitney prefers:

> JURY-MAST, a temporary mast. (Scand.?) '*Jury-mast*, a yard set up instead of a mast that is broken down by a storm or shot, and fitted with sails, so as to make a poor shift to steer a ship;' Kersey, [*Dictionarium Anglo-britannicum*] ed. 1715. Of unknown origin. **β.** Doubtless a sailor's word, and presumably of Du[tch] or Scand[inavian] origin. A probable source is Dan[ish] *kiűre*, a driving, from *kiőre*, to drive; common in compounds, as in *kiűre-hest*, a draught-horse, *kiőrevei*, a carriage-way. Cf. Norw[egian] *kyőre*, a drive, a journey without a stoppage; Swed[ish] *kűra*, Icel[andic] keyra, to drive. In this view, a jury-mast is one by help of which a vessel drives along. **¶** The supposition that it is short for *injury-mast* is most unlikely, owing to the difference in accent.

The fact that Skeat doesn't address the humorous "*jury* + *mast*" theory is regrettable, especially since that theory seems to have become, perhaps by default, one of the leading etymological explanations today.

But the obscure nautical joke explanation arose at a time when the earliest known *jury-* term was *jury-mast* from either 1616 or 1592. That *jury-* has subsequently been discovered more than a century earlier in the form *jory saile* complicates the situation significantly. Hans Kurath, [*Middle English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RecKalDJUicC&pg=PA411&dq=%22Middle+English%22+jory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsptfS4qfUAhUFxWMKHcF3CWQQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Middle%20English%22%20jory&f=false), volume 11 (1969) offers this entry for *jorī-seil*:

> **jorī-seil** n. {Cp. OF *jöerie*, *jüerie* joke, jesting, play, etc. also cp. MnE jury-mast.} ?A temporary sail. (1468–70) in Sandahl *ME Sea Terms* 2 47: j meson seil, j jory saile.

If French words referring to "joke, jest, or play" are indeed the source of *jory* (which I have not seen argued elsewhere than in Kurath, who is careful to bring them up merely in the form of a comparison), then the underlying idea would be that the a *jory-seil* is a joke-sail or play-sail, not a real one—and likewise a *jury-mast* (for example) is joke-mast or play-mast.

---

***Conclusion***

I have not found any firm consensus as to the origin of *jury* (in the sense in which it functions in terms such as *jury mast* and *jury-rigged*) beyond the useful observation that it appears to have reached modern English from the Middle English form *jory*. Nevertheless, there appears to be fairly strong agreement that its origin is not to be found in the hypothetical truncation, at an early date, of the word *injury*.

Answer (score 0):

"A Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue" (London, 1788) "suggests that *jury mast* has a French origin. They indicate that it descends from "journiere" mast, a temporary or emergency replacement mast constructed just for the day or just for this voyage. Thus no connections to the later "jury" or "Jerry" interpretations.

https://archive.org/stream/b2876190x#page/n279/mode/2up

Comment: What does this add to Sven's answer above? Please take the time to read the other answers. See the paragraphs under John Shipley and Francis Grose

Comment: Also, welcome to ELU, knowledge is welcome here. You’ll be able to add a comment to other answers once you gain enough reputation (you’re not far off it now). It might be easiest to garner rep from new or active questions.

Answer (score -1):

I think "jury mast" is a shortening of "jury-rigged mast". The OED mentions that the term originated in the nautical realm. The link above notes a possible etymology from the Middle English jory saile, temporary sail (possibly from the French jour, day, indicating its temporary nature).

Comment: And why do you think that? The first citation of *jury-mast* the OED has is in 1616. The first citation of *jury-rig* the OED has is in 1788.

Comment: What is very surprising is that the OED doesn't list the Middle English [*jory saile*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jury), which is probably where *jury-mast* comes from.